# CPU Intensive SQL Query Optimization

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I optimize this Oracle SQL query as it takes approximately 23 seconds to execute and it also increases CPU usage? The query is meant to get all parent_users and their respective child_users transactions aggregates. The tables structure is including after the Query.

```
        SELECT

        mydb.USERS.first_name,
        mydb.USERS.last_name,
        mydb.USERS.work_id,
        mydb.USERS.unique_id as parent_user_id,

        (SELECT SUM(mydb.TRANSACTIONS.amount) FROM mydb.TRANSACTIONS, mydb.USERS childUsers WHERE mydb.TRANSACTIONS.FROM_UNIQUE_ID = childUsers.unique_id AND childUsers.parent_id = mydb.USERS.unique_id
         ) AS transaction_value,

        (SELECT COUNT(mydb.TRANSACTIONS.txn_id) FROM mydb.TRANSACTIONS, mydb.USERS childUsers WHERE mydb.TRANSACTIONS.FROM_UNIQUE_ID = childUsers.unique_id AND childUsers.parent_id = mydb.USERS.unique_id
         ) AS transaction_volume,

        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT mydb.WORK_ZONE.id) FROM mydb.WORK_ZONE
         WHERE mydb.USERS.work_id = mydb.WORK_ZONE.id AND mydb.WORK_ZONE.status = 1
         ) AS active_zones_count,

         (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT childUsers.city_id) FROM mydb.USERS childUsers
         WHERE  mydb.USERS.unique_id = childUsers.parent_id
         ) AS active_city_count,


        (SELECT COUNT(childUsers.parent_id) FROM mydb.USERS childUsers GROUP BY childUsers.parent_id HAVING  mydb.USERS.unique_id = childUsers.parent_id) AS child_users_count,

         (SELECT COUNT(mydb.TRANSACTIONS.status) FROM mydb.TRANSACTIONS, mydb.USERS childUsers WHERE mydb.TRANSACTIONS.status = 'SUCCESS' AND mydb.TRANSACTIONS.FROM_UNIQUE_ID = childUsers.unique_id AND childUsers.parent_id = mydb.USERS.unique_id
         ) AS success_count,

         (SELECT COUNT(mydb.TRANSACTIONS.status) FROM mydb.TRANSACTIONS, mydb.USERS childUsers WHERE mydb.TRANSACTIONS.status = 'FAILED' AND mydb.TRANSACTIONS.FROM_UNIQUE_ID = childUsers.unique_id AND childUsers.parent_id = mydb.USERS.unique_id
         ) AS failed_count

        FROM mydb.USERS

        LEFT JOIN mydb.TRANSACTIONS ON mydb.TRANSACTIONS.FROM_UNIQUE_ID = mydb.USERS.unique_id

        LEFT JOIN mydb.WORK_ZONE ON WORK_ZONE.id = USERS.work_id

        WHERE mydb.USERS.user_type = :user_type AND mydb.USERS.parent_id IS NULL

        AND substr(mydb.TRANSACTIONS.created_at,0,10) > :start_date AND substr(mydb.TRANSACTIONS.created_at,0,10) < :end_date AND mydb.USERS.region_name LIKE :region_name AND mydb.WORK_ZONE.zone LIKE :zone 

        GROUP BY  USERS.unique_id, USERS.first_name, USERS.last_name, USERS.work_id

        OFFSET :offset ROWS
        FETCH NEXT :per_page ROWS ONLY
```

## TABLES STRUCTURE

- USERS TABLE

unique_id | parent_id | user_type | first_name | last_name | work_id | city_id | region_name

85000061370 |    null    | 90 | John     | Doe       | 3     | null | null

50474671481 | 85000061370| 91 | James     | Wayne    | null  | null | null

60373735474 | 85000061370| 91 | Samuel     | Tony    | null  | null | null

- TRANSACTIONS TABLE

txn_id       | from_unique_id | amount | status | created_at

622160546487 | 50474671481    | 10000  | SUCCESS| 2021-05-28 00:09:00 +01:00

474837593733 | 60373735474 | 5000    | SUCCESS    | 2021-06-20 00:09:00 +01:00

- WORK_ZONE TABLE

id | zone | status

5 | SOUTH EAST | 1

6 | SOUTH WEST | 0

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result/

Comment: Please **edit your question** to show the definitions of all the tables involved in this query, including all indexes. Thanks.

Comment: Okay I will do that shortly.

Comment: LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing makes no sense.

Comment: Please use modern jon syntax. It's difficult to read those subqueries.

Comment: Can you post an EXPLAIN? 
Can you also please post proper DDL, including indices?

Comment: I would suggest you investigate the with clause using the materialize hint. I recently modified another developers query similar to yours (multiple embedded sub queries) which took ~17 seconds to run in ~.223 seconds using a properly structured with clause.

Comment: If you want a bit more explanation, I can create an answer with links & a better explanation.